# Python socket - sending messages to multiple clients on separate threads?

Tags: python, sockets

this is my code:

```
from socket import *
import threading
import datetime

logFile = open("log.txt", "a")
HOST = 'MY LOCAL IP'
PORT = 1289
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT)) 
s.listen(5)

def clientHandler():
    print("Thread successful")
    connect, address = s.accept()
    print(address, "has connected.")
    while 1:
        data = connect.recv(1024)
        print("> ", repr(data))


print("Server started...")
for i in range(5):
    makeThread =   threading.Thread(target=clientHandler)
    makeThread.daemon = True
    makeThread.start()
```

The issue is that I can't send a message back to all clients? As they are on separate threads. How can i fix this to make a sort of group chat?

All help appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: After receiving data from `recv`, you should `send` it to all open sockets. For that you should have a global list of client connections (sockets returned by `accept`), that you should iterate on. You should also update that list when a socket disconnects. _Note_: at the end instead of having daemon threads, you should iterate on the existing client connections and close them properly. also you should have a loop at the end, otherwise when the 5th connection is made, your program will exit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried adding what you said and ended up with an error when I ran the server and tried sending a message with my client code, here's my new code: https://pastebin.com/wTqMuKCM                                However, I get the error ''OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"

Comment: You don't send data on `s`. That one is used only for accepting new connections. You should use `item.send(data)`.